# Ruby On Rails: Accessing value from associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I posted on here as you guys are a lot more helpful than the books have been for me in the past! Please excuse as i am still learning.

I have a Landlord MGT App which has a a **House model** and a **Tenant Model**. On the show page for the house i would like to see the tenant which has the associated house_id in its model.

**show page for house**

```
.wrapper_with_padding
  %h1.showheading= 'Property Information'
  #house_show
    %p First Line Address: #{@house.doorno} #{@house.house_title}
    %p Description:  #{@house.description}
    %p Tenant:  #{@tenant.house.tenant_id}
```

Currently the above line of code for Tenant does not work and pulls NULL value.

**Models**

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tenant
```

---

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :house
```

I have nothing in my controller for show.

In summary the tenant table has a house_id attribute. On the show page for that specific house i would like to see the associated tenant_id.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason for you to have `@tenant` declared. You can access `@house`'s related tenant object via `@house.tenant` and to get the id, just use `@house.tenant.id`.

Edit: Your associations are wrong. See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations

Because Tenant has the column house_id, it `belongs_to :house`.

That means that the house `has_one :tenant` (can also be `has_many` if you're into that sorta thing). Fix that, then try what I wrote above.

Comment: Hi @RichardLegacy thanks for the answer. I tried this but get an error 'undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass' i have checked and this particular property has a house_id field with the particular house.

Comment: Great stuff! Worked a treat. I need to build my knowledge on rails associations for sure!

Comment: The 'guides.rubyonrails.org` articles are all VERY good. Really recommend reading through them all once and then coming back to them whenever you need them.